# How to edit Wiki Markup more efficiently?

Tags: editor, wiki, markup

I'm adding a simple table into our project's wiki page and I'm just wondering whether there is way for the table to have the auto-fill capability like Excel. For ex., auto generating index for all the rows, or fill specific column a same value for all rows.

On the Rich-Text Editor of wiki I cannot do nothing except manual input, but I found this markup format and wondering if I can do some tricks there. So any other tips of of efficiently editing wiki pages will be helpful too.

EDIT: Did a little Google and looks to me this wiki markup is not standard over all wikis, but is there any common tool or script people use?

Comment: This question is on Super User, too: http://superuser.com/q/608916/151741

Comment: Ya, duplicated it hoping for more replies, apparently it didn't work out well.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Bob Swift's table macro](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.swift.confluence.table) for a start.

For table filling, the only method I know of effecting that type of change is to use JQuery or JavaScript on the page via the `{html}` macro.